Troubleshoot Memory Utilization on Passenger
We are running the community edition of Phusion Passenger to host our application.  We have noticed that the mem_used_percent continues to increase after restart.  In our test and staging environments where we are running smaller instance sizes (t3.medium) and have only 4 GB of memory, this goes on until the server runs out of memory and crashes.  Here is what that looks like:

In production, we are running a bit larger instance class (t3.large) which has 8 GB of memory.  This is where it gets interesting as the mem_used_percent seems to climb and then level off.

Any advice on what might be going on here and best practices for troubleshooting/isolating the issue?
NOTE: Even though it appears to "level off", there is a bit of an up turn, so I feel like it will eventually run out of memory even on production.
Thanks in advance.
